# My car doesnot start/run with petrol... but it smoothly starts/runs on CNG, suggestions please

Tags: starting, gasoline, cng

2012-Toyota-Premio, 1500-Sedan. 
Car has DUAL-FUEL: Petrol and CNG.

I ran with CNG for 2 months now can start or run with petrol,

What went wrong? how to fix this...

Comment: If you can start or run with petrol what is the question? Title does not match question body.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the fuel-pump. It is normally immersed and cooled and lubricated by the fuel. If you drive a lot without Petrol, chances are it is broken.